# Are earphones and headphones regional?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have an MSi laptop that I purchased from Newegg in the USA and I have since moved to China. I bought a pair of Chinese earphones that work with my desktop, however it does not work with my laptop. However other earphones work with my laptop.

When asking my IT guy about this strange situation, he told me that Chinese earphones probably don't work with your laptop. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

If the socket is for headsets (earphone / microphone with one 3.5mm jack), there are two systems how the contacts are used. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#TRRS_standards

You can get an adapter to change between systems. Actually my headsets from China always come with an adapter.

Comment: Can you provide a link of what these adapters would look like?

Comment: Something like this http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=37236167023&ali_refid=a3_420434_1006:1102626151:N:%B6%FA%BB%FA%B6%FE%BA%CF%D2%BB%D7%AA%BD%D3%CD%B7:275146bd9173496477ec3be9b27f5931&ali_trackid=1_275146bd9173496477ec3be9b27f5931&spm=a230r.1.17.20.pyr7kh